# How do I run a display at a resolution higher than recommended without 'Input Not Support'?

Tags: display, resolution

I have been using an old monitor with a native resolution of 1366x768 with a laptop with an HDMI to VGA converter. When I [force it to run at 1920x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGEbM.jpg) it [shows an error "Input Not Support"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1lDh.jpg) which keeps floating around the screen. At 1920x1080 the text and image quality is actually pretty usable so is there a way to disable the warning message?

Edit: I know that the monitor is physically incapable of displaying the pixels, could there be a software solution to suppress the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a warning, it's an error. This monitor doesn't support resolution that high. It doesn't have that many pixels or hardware to downscale higher-res input.

If you insist on outputting 1920×1080, you need something to downscale it to 1366×768 before it reaches the monitor, like the [OSSC](https://videogameperfection.com/products/open-source-scan-converter/). Given the cost, it's probably not an acceptable solution though.